# Is this the right place to ask about Kinematics or AI?

Tags: discussion, scope

Since this site is called "Electronics and Robotics", can I ask questions about non-electronic parts of robotics? E.G. Kinematics or AI.

Comment: This should be posted on meta, btw yes this should be fine.

Comment: Whoops, I actually meant to ask this on meta. I was just in the wrong tab!

Answer (score 5):

Yep - go for it. So long as it relates to electronics; ie. kinematics of robotic arms or AI for your coffee maker, etc.; not kinematics of judo moves or discussion of Star Trek Data's AI. :D

... unless you're Doctor Noonien Soong, then go ahead with the Data questions.